# Tkinter: Unable to send data via subprocess.PIPE

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, pipe

I want to do send & receive data program. No data sent to `receive.py` and when I close tkinter GUI, I get an empty list.

**sender.py**

```
import Tkinter as tk
import sys

def send(x):
    sys.stdout.write(x)
    return sys.stdout.flush()

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()
        self.entry.pack()

    def on_button(self):
        x = ''.join(str(self.entry.get()))
        return send(x)

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

**receive.py**

```
import subprocess
import time

xx = subprocess.Popen(["python","sender.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if xx.stdout.readlines():
        print xx.stdout.readlines()
    else:
        print "wait data"
```

Comment: How do you start your programs? They need to be connected in a "pipe" for the pipe forwarding to work.

Comment: Also note that in `receive.py` the first time you call `xx.stdout.readlines()` it reads all the lines, so there won't be any left when you call it the second time.

Comment: What's `piiipe.py`?

Comment: @martineau piiipe.py == sender.py

Comment: @martineau when change xx.stdout.readlines() to xx.stdout.readline() nothing happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you're trying to get data back from `sender.py` in `receive.py`. Your code with the changes shown below seems to work for me. Note I cleaned-up your Tkinter GUI code to only do what was necessary.

#### sender.py

```
import Tkinter as tk
import sys

def send(x):
    sys.stdout.write(x)
    sys.stdout.flush()

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Get", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.focus_set()  # added (optional)

    def on_button(self):
        x = ''.join(str(self.entry.get()))
        send(x)

app = SampleApp()
app.mainloop()
```

#### receive.py

```
import subprocess

with subprocess.Popen(["python","sender.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                      shell=True).stdout as output:
    for line in output:
        print(line)
```

Comment: no data send to receive.py 
i should close gui to receive data

Comment: fadymalak: I also don't see any output until the GUI closed. I suspect this has something to do with the Tkinter `mainloop()`. It may also be OS-specific. I'm running Windows. If you're not, try removing the `shell=True` keyword argument.

Comment: fadymalak: This might work better if you used the `multiprocessing` module and a `multiprocessing.Queue` instead of `subprocess` and a `subprocess.PIPE` to send data from the sender to the receiver.